# when is php executed on apache2?

Tags: php, apache2, execute

I am trying to figure out when exacly are php scripts interpreted on apache server via mod_php in connection lifetime(tcp session lifetime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP scripts are executed by Apache in response to HTTP requests. A HTTP request requires a fully established TCP connection.

Comment: Hmm if i understand you, apache must then fully receive ALL data from client including request post(sended files) data, before PHP script execution? So there is no way to kill connection thru php if cookies doesn't match up with login information in database?

Comment: If you need to send large POST data, split data upload and login. Use a small HTTP GET to establish the session.